# Spring Boot Admin: Error while reading logfile: -

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

When I'm tapping on the log button corresponding to my application of spring boot admin dashboard I'm getting `Error while reading logfile: -` error. Does somebody faced this already?
I'm using log4j with such configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE}] [%-5p] [%c{1}] [%t] [%m]%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10KB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="file" value="service-rest.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE}] [%-5p] [%c{1}] [%t] [%m]%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

My application.yml file has such logging section:

```
logging:
  file: "service-rest.log"
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        boot:
          autoconfigure:
            logging: DEBUG
```

Also I could get that logfile from app directly `http://url/actuator/logfile`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the slightly wrong format of logs that has been pushed to `service-rest.log` file. The right one appender for file is

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
    <param name="file" value="tvpp-rest.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] [%t] [%m]%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Without that brackets around time and log level.

Answer (score 0):

In the Spring Boot 3.x version, I use the `logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size` property to give a log file size but After I removed this property, this **error was gone.**